# What is the meaning of the Haskell operator "<>"?

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, what is the meaning of the `<>` operator (as distinct from `<*>` or `<$>`). I am seeing references to it while researching [the optparse-applicative package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative). Neither Google nor LYAH seem to have any information.

Comment: You can also use [hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=%3C%3E) to search for info on Haskell operations and functions.

Comment: Be sure to read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info

Comment: You may want to check out https://haskell-lang.org/tutorial/operators

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's an alias for [`mappend`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#v:mappend), from the [`Data.Monoid`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html) module.

```
(<>) :: Monoid m => m -> m -> m
(<>) = mappend
```

`mappend` smashes two monoidal values together. For example, using the list monoid,

```
ghci> [1,2,3] <> [4,5,6]
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

When you see a function you don't recognise, you can often find it on API search engines like [Hoogle](http://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%3C%3E&scope=set%3Astackage) or [Hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=%3C%3E).