# Use of Aeson pairs results in error "not in scope '<>'"

Tags: haskell, aeson

I am trying to use Aeson to deal with json in haskell, in the documentation it shows the syntax for toEncoding as this:

```
toEncoding (Person name age) = pairs ("name" .= name <> "age" .= age)
```

however, when I try to compile this I get the error:

```
Not in scope: ‘<>’
Perhaps you meant one of these:
  ‘<*>’ (imported from Control.Applicative),
  ‘>>’ (imported from Control.Monad),
  ‘<$>’ (imported from Control.Applicative)
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to import (<>) somehow?

Comment: "do I need to import (<>) somehow?" -- Yes; add `import Data.Monoid` to your imports. You can search for Haskell identifiers (including operators) using [Hoogle](https://www.stackage.org/lts/hoogle).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of the Haskell operator "<>"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38838688/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-haskell-operator)

Comment: @duplode That should be an answer

Comment: @jkeuhlen I didn't answer because I expected this question to be closed, either as a typo or as a duplicate. I suggest you flag it as a duplicate of the question mentioned by Alexis King just above.

Comment: @duplode Fair enough. I was just skimming the unanswered questions and figured I'd mention it.