# Compare list of lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Supposing my list defined as `[[Id, time, priority] , [Id, time, priority], [Id, time, priority] ... ]`

In This exemple, i want to order my lists in an increasing way depending on the priorities and if I have two equal priorities I order them depending on the time (whoever has the greatest time comes first):

From this :
`[["43525", "5", "2"],["25545", "7", "5"],["7455", "3", "4"],["3586", "8", "2"]]`

To this :
`[[3586, 8, 2], [43525, 5, 2], [7455, 3, 4], [25545, 7, 5]]`

First, I convert all the strings to Int using read fucntion and mapping on all elements :

`map (map (read :: String -> Int)) [["43525", "5", "2"],["25545", "7", "5"],["7455", "3", "4"],["3586", "8", "2"]]`

Comment: Are you sure that this is the way you want to represent this data? The thing about lists is that they are variable length containers, so it's sort of self defeating to use them to represent things that always have 3 elements.  I would think a tuple `[(Id, time, priority),(Id, time, priority)]` or even a record type would be much nicer format to work with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i m very beginner in HASKELL, and i m wondering if there any difference or if it will cause any problem to use list instead of tuples ?

Comment: @Elfi: yes, with tuples, it has a fixed number of elements, and the elements can have different types, with a list, it has an arbitrary number of elements, all of the same type.

Comment: @Elfi For example, the way you're using a list to hold different kinds of thing is forcing you to use `String` values to represent times and priorities; two concepts that should almost certainly use different types. Using tuples would allow each concept to use the most appropriate type instead of all being the same. It also makes it much easier to order a list of the tuples based on a particular field in the tuple (without needing to worry about what happens if the sub-lists are too short to have an item at that index).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define custom sort function and use `sortBy` from `Data.List`:

```hs
import Data.List

toSort = map (map (read :: String -> Int)) [["43525", "5", "2"],["25545", "7", "5"],["7455", "3", "4"],["3586", "8", "2"]]
sortLGT x y = compare (x!!2) (y!!2) -- compare priorities 
    <> compare (y!!1) (x!!1) -- compare time in descending order

sortBy sortLGT toSort
```

Output:

```
[[3586,8,2],[43525,5,2],[7455,3,4],[25545,7,5]]
```

Or as [@Daniel Wagner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/791604/daniel-wagner) suggests in the comments, use `sortOn`, which should be better option:

```hs
sortOn (\[_id, time, prio] -> (prio, Data.Ord.Down time)) toSort
```

Comment: In most cases, `sortOn` is more convenient for the programmer; and often is *also* more efficient. Using it would look like `sortOn (\[_id, time, prio] -> (prio, time)) toSort`.

Comment: And to sort descending by time, you can wrap it in `Data.Ord.Down`: `sortOn (\[_id, time, prio] -> (prio, Data.Ord.Down time))`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !! Can you explain what <> do ?

Comment: @Elfi was glad to help. For `<>` operator - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38838948/2501279) answer. As for what it does with `Ordering` (type returned by compare) - see the [implementation](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/blob/master/libraries/base/GHC/Base.hs#L415) - basically it takes left ordering unless it is `EQ`.